# How to .focus() a .srcElement / childNode in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am attempting to .focus() a text box when a user clicks on a larger div. The input is a child of the div and I can locate the element, however Javascript throws an error upon attempting the .focus() function.

I have already tried to directly .focus() the childNodes as shown but I cannot 1) focus the node and 2) locate the input tag in the list.

```
function clickables() {
    let clickables = document.getElementsByClassName("clickables")
    for (var i = 0; i < clickables.length; i++) {
        clickables[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            const target = e.srcElement.childNodes;
            target.focus(input); // .getElementsByTagNames isn't working
        }); 
    }
}
clickables();
```

The expected results is that upon clicking the larger div it will focus the input inside of it, the actual result is java script tossing an error.

Comment: Dosen't childNodes return an array? So maybe you have to loop through the node?

Comment: Please post the exact error as well

Comment: It would be really helpful that you give us the full html and js code. In a codepen, jsfiddle or so.

Comment: @Vinaayakh TypeError: e.srcElement.childNodes.getElementsByTagName is not a function

Comment: You should probably avoid giving a variable the same name as the function it is in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should be using `inputs.length` and not `clickables.length`.

Second you need to pick which child to `.focus()`.

```js
function clickables() {
  let inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("clickables");
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      const target = e.srcElement.firstElementChild;
      target.focus();
    }); 
  }
}

clickables();
```

```css
.clickables {
  background-color: #999;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="clickables">
  <input type="text" value="first"> 
  <input type="text" value="second">
  <input type="text" value="third">
</div>
```

In this example I am picking the first element to focus on.

**UPDATE**

As stated you need to know *which* child you want to call `.focus()` on.

Let's say that you use the attribute `autofocus` on the child you want to receive focus then you can do this:

```js
function clickables() {
  let inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("clickables");
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      let target = e.srcElement.querySelector('[autofocus]');
      if (!target) {
        target = e.srcElement.firstElementChild;
      }
      target.focus();
    }); 
  }
}

clickables();
```

```css
.clickables {
  background-color: #999;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="clickables">
  <input type="text" value="first"> 
  <input type="text" value="second" autofocus>
  <input type="text" value="third">
</div>
<hr>
<div class="clickables">
  <input type="text" value="first"> 
  <input type="text" value="second">
  <input type="text" value="third" autofocus>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="clickables">
  <input type="text" value="first"> 
  <input type="text" value="second">
  <input type="text" value="third">
</div>
```

Since @sean indicated, correctly, that the above example is a miss use of `autofocus` you should probably use a different attribute or here is an alternate way to accomplish the same thing:

```js
function clickables() {
  let inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("clickables");
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      let index = Number(e.srcElement.getAttribute('focus')||'1')-1;
      console.log(index)
      let target = e.srcElement.children[index];
      target.focus();
    }); 
  }
}

clickables();
```

```css
.clickables {
  background-color: #999;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="clickables" focus="2">
  <input type="text" value="first"> 
  <input type="text" value="second">
  <input type="text" value="third">
</div>
<hr>
<div class="clickables" focus="3">
  <input type="text" value="first"> 
  <input type="text" value="second">
  <input type="text" value="third">
</div>
<hr>
<div class="clickables">
  <input type="text" value="first"> 
  <input type="text" value="second">
  <input type="text" value="third">
</div>
```

> I think the attribute is the best solution since you can guarantee setting `.focus` on the correct/expected element.

Comment: This is great except I have multiple elements children and the order is specific, and .getElementsByTagName throws an error, is there anyway to filter to specifically input tags?

Comment: This is a misuse of the [`autofocus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#autofocus) attribute, which tells browsers to focus the input automatically on page load. Suggest using a custom `data-*` attribute or a class instead.

Comment: That may be but you can use ANY attribute to do this. This is just one way to let the code know which input field to focus on when the `<div>` is clicked on. The nice feature of using `autofocus` is that the first `<div>` will have the correct element focused.

Comment: Yes, you can use any attribute to do this. But using `autocomplete` will automatically focus the first `<input>` on page load. This can create accessibility issues, and the author of the question has not said they want the input automatically focused on page load. Better to use a different attribute than introduce unwanted behavior.

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like

```
function clickables() {
let inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("clickables")
for (var i = 0; i < clickables.length; i++) {
    clickables[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        const childElements = e.srcElement.children;
        for (var j = 0; j < childElements.length; j++) {
            childElements[j].focus();
        }
    }); 
}
}
clickables();
```

Comment: This won't work since you get the list of element in the `inputs` variable and then try to iterate on `clickables`, which is a function.